# JavaScript: Order in which variable assignment takes place

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and would like to understand the order in which variable assignment takes place.  Let's assume I have the following toy example:

```
var foo = document.sentence.split(',');
```

Do we split the sentence first, then assign the output of `split` to the `foo` variable?  Or, do we first create the `foo` variable, and then assign the output of `document.sentence.split(',')` to `foo`?

Thanks!

Comment: It always runs right to left - first the variable `sentence` is split, then it's stored in the variable `foo`

Comment: Actually when using any `var` to define variables they get "hoisted" to the top of the scope (same as having `var foo;` as first line) so foo would get created first in this case. Though as of release of ES6 standard we have `let` to declare variables which would work right to left as Kinglish mentioned.

Comment: @Photon — when describing variable hoisting it is better described as splitting the definition from the assignment, hoisting the definition to the top of scope, and then, later, assigning it the value. So `function x() {  a(); var foo = b(); c(foo); }` gets converted (logically) into something like `function x() {var foo; a(); foo = b(); c(foo); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `var` things are a little different, because of [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting).

> Hoisting works with variables too, so you can use a variable in code before it is declared and/or initialized.
>
> However JavaScript only hoists declarations, not initializations! This means that initialization doesn't happen until the associated line of code is executed, even if the variable was originally initialized then declared, or declared and initialized in the same line.

Example:

```js
'option strict';
function myFunction() {
  console.log(foo);
  // => undefined
  var sentence = 'my,array,of,strings';
  var foo = sentence.split(',');
  console.log(foo);
  // => ['my', 'array', 'of', 'strings']
}
myFunction();
```

On the first `console.log(foo)` we didn't get a `Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined` error. That's what would normally happen if we tried to access a variable that hadn't been declared yet.

If we try the same thing using `const` (or `let`), we get a different response:

```js
'option strict';
function myFunction() {
  console.log(foo);
  // => Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'foo' before initialization
  const sentence = 'my,array,of,strings';
  const foo = sentence.split(',');
  console.log(foo);
  // => ['my', 'array', 'of', 'strings']
}
myFunction();
```